# Change string name to custom name from an Object in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, I have an object that returns with some data, I want to customize the values of the data, for example the object is as per below

data.json

```
status: {
    STATUS_ACTIVE
}
```

I want to convert this to "Active" instead, this object returns with multiple values such as STATUS_ACTIVE, STATUS_SUSPENDED etc...

I would appreciate your assistance in helping me achieve this using the below code, and thanks in advance.

employees.component.ts

```
exportAsXLSX(): void {
this.PDFvalidation().forEach(element => {
  this.XLSXData.push(
    {
      "Status": element.status
    }
  )
});
this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.XLSXData, 'Employees');
}
```

Comment: Try `"Status": "Active"`

Comment: Assuming `XLSXData` is a javascript object and you want the additional property at the top level of the resultant json, you should just need to do `XLSXData.Status = element.status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Enums in this situations.

For example:

```
enum StatusResolver {
   'STATUS_ACTIVE' = 'Active',
   'STATUS_INACTIVE' = 'Inactive'
}
```

After you've create your ENUM file for example "status.enum.ts" you can reach it by importing it to your working component.

You can use it like this.

```
function resolveStatus(status: string, response: StatusResolver): void {
// ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you